# How to determine what object rise InvalidCastException in class assignment?

Tags: c#, casting, exception

I have a class assignment like that:

```
Variable currentVar = new Variable() { 
Id = var.Field<int>("id"), 
Address = var.Field<string>("address"), 
Matricola = var.Field<int>("matricola"),
MachModel = var.Field<string>("modello"),
MachType = var.Field<string>("machinetype"),
Part = var.Field<string>("part"),
PartNumber = var.Field<int>("partnumber"),
PartMeasurement = var.Field<string>("partmeasurement"),
Priority = var.Field<int>("priority") , 
EnableEventHub = var.Field<bool>("enableeventhub"),
MinAgeEventHub = var.Field<int>("minageeventhub")};
```

Sometime it rise an InvalidCastException. When I debug the application I cannot see what "var" values are because they're in another context, and the line reference on the stack report the first because it is only one statement.
What is a good way to determine what field of "var" gives me the exception?
My block is in a normal try catch and I log the exception message and stack.

Comment: First point: I'd *strongly* recommend against using `var` as the name of a variable, given that it's also a contextual keyword. Have you tried stepping through the code, or breaking when the exception is thrown so you can have a look at the variable at that point?

Comment: It looks like X-Y problem. If `var.Field` can throw an exception, then there should be a `bool TryGetField<T>(string, out T value)` method. If this is your own API, then I'd recommend you to write one. This is much better, that researching for the line, that throws exception.

Comment: @Dennis does tryget cause a loss of performance? In normal conditions the exception will never rise and using the tryget seems to me usefull.. I just wanna have better debugging when data are wrong..

Comment: @Jon skeet ,  the problem is that in the exception the variable var is no more accessible... Doesn't exist a property in the exception catched to obtain the context?

Comment: When the exception is thrown, `var` *will* be accessible, in the stack frame containing the code you've shown. So as long as you get the debugger to break when the exception is thrown, it should be fine. Does the `InvalidCastException` provide any details? (Sometimes it will, sometimes it won't.)

Comment: @Jon unfortunately no details are given into exception.. Yeah var is accessible but that assignment is into a for loop,  so I can only see the exception when is catched,  and in that moment var is no more accessible. I think the only way by now is defining var outside the try

Comment: Again, it doesn't have to be like that. Change the debugger exception settings to break when InvalidCastException is thrown, and it won't get as far as your `catch` block.

Comment: Whoa! I understand now! :D This info opened to me a new world :) :) :) Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to assign all data before you declare the class.

Like that:

```
int iMatricola = var.Field<int>("matricola");
string strAddress = var.Field<string>("address");


 Variable currentVar = new Variable() { 
                            Address = strAddress, 
                            Matricola = iMatricola
};
```

I prefer this way if I have to use not type-safe values.

Comment: Yeah, by now that's the only solution I think